# Passing the calling object as a parameter in a chained method in Swift

Tags: swift, methods, parameters

Not sure if the title makes sense or not.  I've been searching for an answer for a while, and having trouble putting into words what I am looking for.

When you call certain built in methods on a String in Swift you would do something like this.

```
someString.lowerCased()
```

How does the `lowerCased()` method get `someString` as it's parameter to modify?

Basically, I am writing an extension for the String type that checks certain things about the string and throws an error if certain conditions aren't met.  So I would like to just be able to write

```
someString.checkString()
```

But instead, right now, I am having to write it as

```
someString.checkString(stringToCheck: someString)
```

I swear I remember reading something about this a long time ago, but can't remember anything about it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `self`. Useless but to the point example:

```
extension String {
    func checkString(ifLongerThan number: Int) -> Bool {
        return self.characters.count > number
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  That makes sense now looking at it. Thanks!